# How can I mute Windows 7 volume from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, windows, volume

How can I mute my user's Windows volume (the one sitting on the taskbar in the bottom right corner)?

OKAY IT CAN'T BE DONE

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't (not without a technology like ActiveX, anyway).

Comment: NO! Ever heard of a sandbox? Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Have you put your question on the correct site? It should maybe go to some Windows-users question&answer site.

Comment: @Tadeck - Question asks how to do it "from a webpage" and is tagged with JavaScript, so I think this is the right place to ask. (Though of course the answer is "You can't.")

Comment: its not possible with javascript....u have to make sure some software connected to webpage just like facebook video chat or google chat applications...

Comment: I have flash audio player however you must lower the volume before using it as it creates interference

Comment: How about lowering the volume of the flash audio?

Comment: i'm also recording. Can that be done using actionscript? I want to lower the mic volume...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun

---

1. Detect user's browser
2. Pair it to a known browser exploit allowing you to run unmanaged code.
3. Use said exploit to execute a system command to mute the user's audio.
4. Recover from the overflow and resume the Browser thread to prevent a crash.

This will be more difficult if the user has DEP / ASLR enabled on their computer. Consider google'ing ROP Payloads.

Comment: I will accept this answer just for fun and for the benefit of others wondering the same thing.